# How to create a polygon area in mapbox

Tags: java, android, mapbox, polygon

I created android app use mapbox ; new, I want to drow polygon area by user and show on map ;

How can I do this in mapbox? [mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use this function:

**Activity**

```
private MapView mapView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
    // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
    Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_token));

    // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        drawPolygon(mapboxMap);
      }
    });
  }
```

Function **drawPolygon:**

```
 private void drawPolygon(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    List<LatLng> polygon = new ArrayList<>();
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.522585, -122.685699));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.534611, -122.708873));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.530883, -122.678833));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.547115, -122.667503));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.530643, -122.660121));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.533529, -122.636260));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.521743, -122.659091));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.510677, -122.648792));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.515008, -122.664070));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.502496, -122.669048));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.515369, -122.678489));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.506346, -122.702007));
    polygon.add(new LatLng(45.522585, -122.685699));
    mapboxMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
      .addAll(polygon)
      .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#CD0000")));
  }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for answer ,but this function drow Polygon programmatically, i want drow it by user in android app!

Answer (score 0):

The mapbox api provides functionality to handle clicks on the map 
`MapboxMap.setOnMapClickListener(OnMapClickListener)`
 (https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/6.4.0/)
which will give you the location.

I suggest that you use these locations to progressively create a polyline, and once the user has finished the polygon, then convert the polyline to a polygon by closing the shape.

User interaction examples: https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/maps/examples/#user-interaction

Answer (score -1):

```
this.map.addSource('maine', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
                  'type': 'Feature',
                  'geometry': {
                                'type': 'Polygon',
                                'coordinates': [
                                    [
                                      [long1, lat1],
                                      [long2, lat2],
                                      [long3, lat3],
                                    ]
                                  ]
                  } 
        }
      });
```

Comment: addSource is not an available option for the map (MapboxMap) object in `mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0`